# routes when trying to make a link_to look like a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had my link for editing brands like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', :action => 'edit', :id => brand %>
```

I found around here a way to make it look like a button, so I did this (not sure why the url helper method needs to be used, but with `:action => 'edit'` it didn't work, it kept thinking it was post action):

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', admin_brand_edit_path(brand), :method => "get" %>
```

However, the generated url is like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/brand/edit.1
```

Where it should be

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/brand/edit/1
```

Result of `rake routes` for brand edit:

```
admin_brand_edit GET  /admin/brand/edit(.:format)        admin/brand#edit
admin_brand_update POST /admin/brand/update(.:format)    admin/brand#update
```

`routes.rb`

```
get 'admin/brand/edit'
```

Comment: Could you share your `routes.rb` please.  You seem to have 2 different routes for `admin/brand#edit`.

Comment: BTW, `button_to` will default to a POST operation which is why you need to override it with method get - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Comment: @GraemeMcLean yes I know that. I posted `routes.rb` and updated `rake routes`. I removed the duplicate route for edit, I was just trying to match the format so it returned the desired action.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused now.  Is your problem solved or not?  I would have expected your route to be more like `get 'admin/brand/:id/edit'` since you want to edit a specific instance.

Comment: when I do it with link to the route is `admin/brand/edit/id`. it is not solved.

Comment: You are not requesting the id in your route, so the unique parameter (id) is assumed to be format. You need to explicitly describe where the id goes in your route. It should be /admin/brand/edit/:id(.:format)